# Screen shot using C++ and MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, screenshot

I have a MFC Application and a I need to build a function that captures a screen shot, but only the open dialog box, not the whole window. I'm new VS and C++ and I'm using VS 2013 in my project. Any Ideas?

Comment: Yes. But, what have you tried?

Comment: Use the built-in one [alt]+[print-screen] ?

Comment: This: http://planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=10754&lngWId=3

Comment: check this link. 

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20367/Screen-Capture-Simple-Win-Dialog-Based